# Report missing noweb references in org-babel

Tags: org-babel, noweb

In `org-babel`, is there a way for checking for missing noweb references `<<...>>` or for throwing an error if a reference is missing?

For example in the following I have mistyped the name of the referenced code block.  Tangling via `C-c C-v f` then produces an elisp file with `<<function-body>>` replaced by nothing and reports no error.

```
#+PROPERTY: header-args :noweb yes :tangle no :exports none

The first code block calls all others.

#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :tangle yes
  (defun test-fn (a b c)
    "A test function"
    <<function-body>>)
#+END_SRC

#+NAME: function-bod
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
  (+ a b c)
#+END_SRC
```

Alternatively, is there a reliable way to make sure I don't type such names incorrectly?

Answer (score 2):

The behavior you want is controlled by the variable `org-babel-noweb-error-all-langs`, whose default value is `nil`. Set it to `t` (e.g. via `(setq org-babel-noweb-error-all-langs t)` in your init file), and unresolvable noweb references will raise an error.

Comment: Very good.  Is this a new feature? It is a pity it is not documented in the info file.

Comment: I can't speak to the age of the feature; it has probably been there a while. It wasn't hard to discover via source diving, but I agree that it would ideally be documented; perhaps you'll submit a patch.

Comment: I had tried diving in to the sources, but only really looked in `ob-tangle.el`.  It turns out this is in `ob-core`.  The git sources tell us this was introduced in June 2014, whereas `org-babel-noweb-error-langs` has been there from the beginning.  I'll seriously consider sending a documentation patch.